# How to inject HttpClient in the constructor of a Blazor page

Tags: blazor

So in our initial page we had

```
@inject HttpClient Http
```

at the top of the page and all was fine. We are now moving our code blocks into code behind to seperate the code from the page. If I remove the above line from the page and then in the code behind do:

```
 [Inject]
 public required HttpClient Http { get; set; }
```

all still works fine. However, we would prefer to have it in the constructor:

```
private HttpClient Http;
public myclass (HttpClient http)
{
    Http = http;
}
```

where and how should I reference HttpClient so that I can use it in the above way?

Comment: Constructor injection is not supported for Blazor components. This is why `@inject`/`[Inject]` exist.

Comment: @Lex Thank you. I did think that was the case, but another dev was adamant that they had done it before, but could not give me an example;.

Comment: @bilpor From Blazor WASM (client side), where HttpClient is provided as a scoped service, you can inject the HttpClient into a *service* using constructor injection.  This might be where your "other dev" was confused.

Comment: @AdamVincent This isn't exclusive to WASM. You can inject HttpClient into services in Blazor Server via the constructor as well.

Comment: @Lex It's only available in server side Blazor AFTER you register it with `builder.Services.AddHttpClient();`

Answer (score 1):

Constructor injection is not yet supported in Blazor components.

To change split this code into a view and codebehind, you'll will still need to use dependency injection via the `InjectionAttribute`

REF: [Partial Class Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#partial-class-support)

### IndexPartial.razor

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
```

### IndexPartial.razor.cs

```cs
public partial class IndexPartial
{
    [Inject]
    HttpClient Http;
}
```

Comment: How is this different from what the OP included in the original question?

Comment: Because it answers the question? The answer is there. `Constructor injection is not supported`, you said it yourself.  It is then followed by a reference to back up the answer. Then it even has a code snippet so you don't have to read the entire reference.

Comment: [Polite] - "Constructor injection is not yet supported in Blazor."  Do you know something I don't?  I think a major (probably breaking) change would be required to instantiate components in the DI context.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I suppose you are asking about "yet"? As I understand it, `@inject` needs reflection to work.  ASP.NET Team has been steadily tackling cases where reflection is used in order to drive native AOT compatibility.  This isn't on the roadmap for sure, but it's not out of the realm of possibility.

Comment: @AdamVincent - as a component writer I was interested.  There are several places in components where [expensive] reflection is used.  I'll be interested to see how they refactor them without breaking changes!

Answer (score 0):

> This answer adds some detail to @Lex's comment.

You can't use "injected" services in a component constructor because they aren't defined in the constructor.  The Renderer instantiates the component outside the DI context.

They are just normal properties labelled with the `Inject` Attribute.  The Renderer uses `IServiceProvider` to get the correct service from the DI container and assigns it to the property via reflection during  the "attach" process. They are available before `SetParametersAsync` is called.

> another dev was adamant that they had done it before

[Respectfully] He didn't, he's confused.

If you want to do stuff before anything is rendered, do it in `SetParametersAsync`.  Here's the basic pattern to use.

```cs
    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        // Do your Stuff
        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }
```